# How to combine multiple rows into one, depening on an ID coming from a different table

Tags: sql, oracle, string-aggregation

I'm trying to add a number of values into one, depending on a value coming from multiple different tables. I keep getting a syntax error. So I have the following table:

| OT_ID | CODE | OPTION | OPTION2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 6T | S34 | A1C |
| 1 | 6T | Y78 | Y08 |
| 1 | 6T | S34 | A1C |
| 2 | 7Y | Y78 | YP8 |
| 2 | 7Y | S34 | A1C |
| 2 | 7Y | Y78 | Y08 |

I want to combine the values in OPTION when the OT_ID is the same.

| OT_ID | CODE | OPTION | OPTION2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 6T | S34,Y78,S34 | A1C,Y08,A1C |
| 2 | 7Y | Y78,S34,Y78 | TP8,A1C,Y08 |

I have tried to following query:

```
SELECT t1.ot_id, t0.code, t2.option, t3.option2
  FROM test t0
  LEFT JOIN test1 t1
    ON t1.ot_id = t0.id
  LEFT JOIN optn t2
    ON t1.ot_id = t2_id
  LEFT JOIN addtopn t3    
    ON t1.ot_id = t3.id
```

I tried `STING_AGG`, but I'm getting a syntax error.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Also show us your STRING_AGG attempt.

Comment: I'm using oracle. I tried STRING_AGG(t2.OPTION, ',') As OPTION WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY t1.ID) t2.OPTION

Comment: Try LISTAGG instead. (STRING_AGG is for MS SQL Server.) https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030